# Angular4 group by filter not working with pipe: ngx-pipes

Tags: json, angular, pipe, angular2-directives

I really trying to filter data that I need, filter products by price and by gender. 
I used [ngx-pipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pipes#groupby), build pipe for sort the data. HTML:

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="ProductCategory" (change)="updateProductCategory($ProductCategory)" name=Gender>
    <option *ngFor="let g of GenderFilter">{{g.DisplayText}}</option>
  </select>
  <select [(ngModel)]="ProductCategory" (change)="updateProductCategory($ProductCategory)" name=Price>
        <option *ngFor= "let k of PriceFilter ">{{k.DisplayText | groupBy: 'Value'}}</option>
    </select>


  <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let store of stores">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let product of store.Products">
          <img src={{product.ProductImage}}>
          <p>store: {{ store.StoreName }}</p>
          <p>Product Price: {{ product.Price | currency}}</p>
        <p>Product Title: {{ product.ProductTitle }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

ts:

```
  ProductCategory;

  updateProductCategory(stringCategory: any) {
  this.ProductCategory = stringCategory;
  }
   //getting the data from JSON
  ngOnInit() {
    this._storeService.getProducts()
   .subscribe(data =>{
    this.products = data.Stores.Products;
    this.filtered = data.PriceFilter.TagId;

    this.stores=data.Stores;});
```

JSONs like:

```
   "PriceFilter": [
    {
      "TagId": 20,
      "Type": "Budget",
      "Value": 5,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "$5",
      "Order": null
    }]
"GenderFilter": [
    {
      "TagId": 3,
      "Type": "Gender",
      "Value": 3,
      "Values": null,
      "DisplayText": "Boy",
      "Order": 1
    }
```

Products:

```
"Stores": [
    {
      "Products": [
        {
 "ProductId": 206419,
 "Price": 39.99,
          "PriceLabel": "$39.99",
          "ProductTags": [1,2,...]
}
]}]
```

My purpose is After selecting one of the values here,to filter the list to include all products with the same tag id [my target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYhQN.png)
how it looks now:
[Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAaR2.png)
Really need help!
Thank you very much!

Edited: 
Console.log(Pricefilter)[PriceFilter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs4Dm.png)

Comment: This won't work on strings like you are trying to do `{{k.DisplayText | groupBy: 'Value'}}` instead it needs an array of objects like `priceFilter`

Comment: @Suryan Thanks ! but nothing change

Comment: Instead use this way `<option *ngFor="let k of PriceFilter | groupBy: 'Value' | keyvalue">{{k | json}}</option>`

Comment: Be sure that you have the priceFilter array containing objects

Comment: @Suryan Thank you. I edied my question so you can see the log. but nothing change

Comment: @Suryan my mistake. I meant to array. my code is `  priceFilter =[]; ...      this.priceFilter = data.PriceFilter; `  it was the spelling :/ but its not filtering my products when choosing a filter What am I doing wrong?
many thanks!

Comment: @Suryan Thank you so much! I need to display products Relative to the selected filter So if we choose a price filter over $ 100, I will receive all the products their price feet, the matching of them is according to TagId they
both have. so It's basically 2 arrays, to group products, according to the filter value and tag..So I tried also this: ` <li *ngFor="let product of store.Products |  groupBy: 'priceFilter.Value'">` but getting the error of cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. I really need products and priceFilter to be connected. appreciate!!

Comment: @Suryan Thank you! looking :)

Comment: @Suryan working for me now also thanks! Just need to connect now products to when clicking the filter the matching products will display

Comment: @Suryan I appreciate it so much! you can see the products after filtering?

Comment: @Suryan Hi I got ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined using       console.log(this.products.filter(val => value.slice(1) >= val['Price']))
do you know why? many thanks!

Comment: Share what have you done... In your case it's gonna be `GenderFilter.Products.Stores.Products.filter...` Else share your code please.

Comment: make a demo on stackblitz, comments are getting too long

Comment: link not working but hopefully this is what you want https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-product-filter-dropdown?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be your snippet

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      filterProduct: ['']
    })
  }

  getValue(index) {
    if(index === 0)
      return { 
        lower: 0, 
        displayText: this.PriceFilter[index].DisplayText, 
        upper: this.PriceFilter[index].Value 
      };
    else {
      return { 
        lower: this.PriceFilter[index - 1].Value, 
        upper: this.PriceFilter[index].Value,
        displayText: `${this.PriceFilter[index - 1].DisplayText} - ${this.PriceFilter[index].DisplayText}`
      };
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredProducts = [...this.Stores[0].Products];

    this.myForm.get('filterProduct').valueChanges.subscribe(
      value => {
        console.log(value);
        this.filteredProducts = [...this.Stores[0].Products.filter(product => product.Price >= value.lower && product.Price <= value.upper )]
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <select name="Price" formControlName="filterProduct">
    <option *ngFor="let k of PriceFilter; let i = index;"
      [ngValue]="getValue(i)">
      {{ getValue(i).displayText }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor= "let product of filteredProducts">
      {{ product | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! and if I want to add GenderFilter? Another filter selecting Female/Male, I can use the same form? Thanks!